# TikZ: how to refer to only one component of a defined coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made a picture showing Newton's method in action:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
            \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

            \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
            \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
            \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
            \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

            \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
            \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
            \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
            \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

            \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
            \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
            \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
            \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

            \coordinate (x0) at (2.25, 0);
            \coordinate (x1) at (3.5, 0);

            \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

            \draw (sp0) .. controls (csp0) and (cep0).. (ep0);
            \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
            \draw[dotted] (ep0) -- (0, 2);
            \draw[dotted] (ep0) -- (3.5, 0);

            \draw (sp1) .. controls (csp1) and (cep1).. (ep1);
            \draw (sp2) .. controls (csp2) and (cep2).. (ep2);

            \draw (3.5,1pt) -- (3.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
            \draw (2.75,1pt) -- (2.75,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
            \draw (1pt, 2) -- (-3pt, 2) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Newton's method in action.}
        \label{fig:newton_method}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Near the end, you can see I have written things like:

```
\draw (3.5,1pt) -- (3.5,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
```

I am trying to put down ticks for an earlier defined coordinate (in this case, `x1`), and I only need its x-component (`3.5`), but I do not know how to refer to it alone, so I refer to it manually. The downside of this is that if I redefine `x1`, then I have to scour the code to find any bits that use only one of its components, and change that too. Already, you can see that I have started to make errors, and I am getting confused as to whether I want to refer to `x1` or `x0`.

How can I refer to only one component in a more automatic fashion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use `let` syntax from the `calc` library. After including

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

we can say things like

```
\draw let \p1 = (x1) in (\x1,1pt) -- (\x1,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
```

which sets the coordinate `x1` to be a point `\p1` whose individual coordinates can be accessed within the statement using `\x1` and `\y1`. This might be confusing since the coordinate in question is named `x1`, so we could have just as easily done

```
 \draw let \p2 = (x1) in (\x2,1pt) -- (\x2,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
```

An additional note: we can use relative coordinates to only require our coordinate location one time:

```
 \draw let \p1 = (x1) in (\x1,1pt) -- ++(0,-4pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
```

Here's the full code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (y) at (0,3);
    \coordinate (x) at (5,0);

    \coordinate (sp0) at (1.5, 0);
    \coordinate (ep0) at (3.5, 2);
    \coordinate (csp0) at (2.5, 1);
    \coordinate (cep0) at (2.75, 0);

    \coordinate (sp1) at (ep0);
    \coordinate (ep1) at (4.5, 3);
    \coordinate (csp1) at (4.25, 4);
    \coordinate (cep1) at (4.25, 2);

    \coordinate (sp2) at (sp0);
    \coordinate (ep2) at (0, -1);
    \coordinate (csp2) at (0.5, -1);
    \coordinate (cep2) at (0.5, -1);

    \coordinate (x0) at (2.25, 0);
    \coordinate (x1) at (3.5, 0);

    \draw[<->] (y) node[left] {$f(x)$} -- (0,0) --  (x) node[below] {$x$};

    \draw (sp0) .. controls (csp0) and (cep0).. (ep0);
    \draw[dashed] (cep0) -- (csp1);
    \draw[dotted] (ep0) -- (0, 2);
    \draw[dotted] (ep0) -- (3.5, 0);

    \draw (sp1) .. controls (csp1) and (cep1).. (ep1);
    \draw (sp2) .. controls (csp2) and (cep2).. (ep2);

    \draw let \p1 = (x1) in (\x1,1pt) -- ++(0,-4pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_0$};
    \draw (2.75,1pt) -- (2.75,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$x_1$};
    \draw (1pt, 2) -- (-3pt, 2) node [anchor=east] {$f(x_0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]